# how do you call a definition with defined parameters, while it has a self parameter?

Tags: python, oop, self

```
import tkinter as tk 

class Main:

    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.GUI()

    def GUI(self):
        label = tk.Label(self.root, text='Hello World')
        label.pack()

    def build(self, title, txt):
        title = tk.Label(self.root, text=txt)
        title.pack()

    build('hello_label', 'helloagainworld')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    Main(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: No, `self` is not bound there.  Probably it needs to be put in `__init__`, I'll leave it to someone with experience in tkinter

Comment: @wim Yep, that's right. My fault for not looking at the code closer. Deleted my comment.

Comment: I can't get the build function to work--to make labels and add them to the main window... it throws an error because I don't have three parameters in the function call--the definition has three parameters, but I only need to send two.

Comment: Who is the definition?

Comment: the build() definition

Comment: @wim that fixed it thank you so much. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code at the toplevel of a class is not executed in the scope of the `self` variable.

You either have to assign the result of `Main(root)` to a variable and call `build()` from there:

```
mymain = Main(root)
mymain.build('hello_label', 'helloagainworld')
```

or call it at the end of `__init__`:

```
def __init__(self, root):
    self.root = root
    self.GUI()
    self.build('hello_label', 'helloagainworld')
```